# How to get rid of undefined value in angular 8?

Tags: angular

Component.ts(In this Valueofcertificate I am getting undefined value.. could you please help me to find out the solution?? I st condition is working as expected but 2nd and 3rd is not working because the value id getting undefined.. Is there anything wrong in my code??)

```
     this.agentShowSpinner = true;
    // this.agentSuccessSubscription.unsubscribe()
    // this.agentErrorSubscription.unsubscribe()
    this.store.dispatch(new GetAllAgents(`${this.userService.getUserdetails().CompanyUser.company_id.id}/true`))
    this.agentSuccessSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(getAllAgentsSuccess)).subscribe((result : any) => {
      if(!!result) {
        this.getAgents = result
        this.getAgents.map(item => item.valueofCertificate = '')
        this.getAgents.forEach(element =>{

          if(element.foodsafetycertificate.length == 0){
              element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates Not Available"
          }
          else{
            let now = new Date
            now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
               element.foodsafetycertificate.forEach(item => {
                      // if(!item.expiry_date){
                      //     element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates Not Available"
                      //   }
                        if(item.expiry_date  >= new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate()))){
                          element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates are Valid"
                            }
                        else if(item.expiry_date <= new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate()))){
                          element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates Expired"
                            }
                         })
                }


        })
        console.log(this.getAgents)
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result)
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }  else {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([])
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
```

Comment: What is `getAllAgentsSuccess` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution works perfectly for me..

```
this.store.dispatch(new GetAllAgents(`${this.userService.getUserdetails().CompanyUser.company_id.id}/true`))
   this.agentSuccessSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(getAllAgentsSuccess)).subscribe((result : any) => {
     if(!!result) {
       this.getAgents = result
       this.getAgents.map(element =>{
               if(element.foodsafetycertificate.length == 0){
                         element['certificateStatus'] = "Not_Available"
                   } else{
                     let certificateStatus = "Valid";
                     element.foodsafetycertificate.map(item =>{
                           let expirydate = new Date(item.expiry_date).getTime()
                           let now = new Date().getTime()
                          if(expirydate < now) {
                           certificateStatus = "Invalid"
                           }
                      })
                      element['certificateStatus'] = certificateStatus
                }
        })

       this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result)
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     }  else {
       this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([])
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     }
     this.agentShowSpinner = false
   })
   this.agentErrorSubscription =  this.store.pipe(select(getAllAgentsError)).subscribe((result : any) => {
     if(!!result) {
       alert(result)
       this.agentShowSpinner = false
       }
     })
   }

   getRowColor(item){
   if (item === "Not_Available") {
     return "red"
   } else if(item === "Valid"){
     return "#00FF00"
   }
   else if(item === "Invalid"){
     return "#DAA520"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getFoodCertificateValues(element: any){
    let now = new Date
    now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    element.foodsafetycertificate.forEach(item => {
      if(!item.expiry_date){
        element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates Not Available"
      }
      else if(item.expiry_date  >= new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate()))){
        element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates are Valid"
          }
       else if(item.expiry_date <= new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate()))){
        element.valueofCertificate = "Certificates Expired"
          }
    })
}
```

For above code, of course it will surely complain undefined because you did not declare **item** property. Even if you declared the **item** property it still complains item undefined because  you did not use any subscription so that **item** property can subscribe and contain the value of that subscription. Furthermore, as I observed, I saw you are using **getFoodCertificateValues** and use **element prorpety**, I assume that you are trying to get the values of specific element. To prevent it, it should be something similar to this

```
item: any; // declare item property
getFoodCertificateValues(element: any){
       this.yourService.yourServiceName(element)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.item = data;
                ... // put entire of your if condition in here
             });
}
```

Let me explain this:

1. for the above code, element property is where the user click/change or do whatever he/she wants on the template. element property will receive the data of that change. Then pass that data to yourServiceName. In there, your service will do GET request and pass that value from element property to the URL, URL then to API, API then does whatever API does when you set it up to get data that for you. Then when the data is ready and sent back,  the data property inside the **.subscribe()** will contains data after API processed. **this.item = data** means **item** property will contain all the values of **data** property
2. if you put the **item** property outside the **.subscribe()**, the **item** property will become undefined even though it is used in **getFoodCertificateValues()** method. So if you want to use **item** property, use it inside **.subscribe()** where I commented out.

> Base on information you provided, that is all I can answer. I hope
>   this help. Corrections are all welcome

Comment: Now I am edited my code whatever i have done changes... but still i am getting undefined or " " empty value like this..you could check my above code..

Comment: can you copy and paste the error into here? I may need to know which property it complains undefined

Comment: Does your database has the column **valueofcertificate**? as I see you use **element.foodsafetycertificate** and it does not complain so which mean the database has **foodsafetycertificate**. There is posibility that you don't have **valueofcertificate** so that when you use **element.valueofcertificate** it will complain undefined

Comment: yes, valueofcertificate i need to add it from frontend in order to change the status of the certificate according to button color will change.. wat i need to do to add the value from the fronend?? could you make stackblitz for this??

Comment: I could but first can you put this `console.log(result)` after this `this.agentSuccessSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(getAllAgentsSuccess)).subscribe((result : any) => {` So it will become `this.agentSuccessSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(getAllAgentsSuccess)).subscribe((result : any) => {console.log(result)`. Then take and add a picture of the console on F12 in here?